# How to create admob app-ads.txt file flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, admob

I have a website made with flutter web. My app which shows google admob ad. Now google admob told me to create an app-ads.txt file on my website . Flutter web is a single page website so, is it possible to create an app-ads.txt file with my flutter web app !?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I also recently tried flutter web. I went on a "fishing expedition", and managed to solve this issue.

What i did:

1. Place your `app-ads.txt` in `<project>/web` folder.
2. Run `flutter build web`
3. Check that `app-ads.txt` appeared in `build/web` folder.
4. Check that in `build/web/flutter_service_worker.js` in `RESOURCES` map appeared a record with key `"app-ads.txt"`(ex. `"app-ads.txt": "4c75380ac52243715a448e96239e0ca5",`)
5. Run `firebase deploy --only hosting`

After this, `app-ads.txt` should be available on `https://your-domain.web.app/app-ads.txt`, `https://your-domain.firebaseapp.com/app-ads.txt` and(if you added a custom domain) on `https://my-custom-domain.com/app-ads.txt`.

**P.S.** If you got redirected from `/app-ads.txt` to your main page, then try to clear your site cache:

1. Press F12
2. Open "Application" tab
3. Choose "Storage"
4. Press "Clear site data"

After this, `app-ads.txt` should be available.

Comment: Even if I try `$ flutter build web`, app-ads.txt are not appeared in `build/web`. I checked that `app-ads.txt` was in `ProjectDir/web`.

Comment: I could solve it↑. I added `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="app-ads.txt">` between `<html><head></head></html>` in `ProjectDir/web/index.html`